# OkHttp is using reflection, which violates Android 9 limitations on non-SDK methods?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

In Android 9 Google announced [new limitations on accessing non-SDK interface methods by using reflection](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces).

If your project uses one, you will get the dialog `Detected problems with API compatibility (visit g.co/dev/appcompat for more info)`. Although as far as I know this dialog will not appear in a release build, it looks like in the future developers would have completely no way to use reflection to do what they want.

By using the `StrictMode` class, I was able to log the reflection methods being used. One of them is called by the OkHttp library:

```
2019-02-01 13:45:43.260 14892-14892/com.xxx.xxx.xxx W/com.xxx.xxx.xxx: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light greylist, reflection)
2019-02-01 13:45:43.261 14892-14892/com.xxx.xxx.xxx D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;
        at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
        at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.getPublicMethodRecursive(Class.java:2075)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2063)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform$CloseGuard.get(AndroidPlatform.java:370)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.<init>(AndroidPlatform.java:58)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.buildIfSupported(AndroidPlatform.java:260)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.findPlatform(Platform.java:201)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:78)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.get(Platform.java:84)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.newSslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:292)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:258)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.build(OkHttpClient.java:1040)
```

I am already using the latest version of the OkHttp library (3.12.1).

How can I get rid of the dialog?

Comment: Hav you got any solution for your question even I am facing the same problem

Comment: Nope, but I guess eventually Square will take care of it